# How to divide the list and sort in ascending and descending order using python?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a python list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` I have to print `[1,2,3,6,5,4]`? First half in ascending order and next half in descending order

Comment: break the big problem into small steps. can you divide (slice) the list? can you reverse a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the half, then reverse:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> l[len(l)//2:]=l[len(l)//2:][::-1]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
>>>
```

slicing + slicing + reversing.

Comment: It only works for a sorted list. It won't work for `[1,2,3,5,6,4]`.

Answer (score 1):

By list slicing:

```
# mix list up a bit
l =  [3,4,1,2,5,6]
len_l = len(l)

l.sort() # sort it again

# print first half, then last half reversed
print(l[0:len_l//2]+l[len_l:len_l//2-1:-1])
```

Output:

```
 [1,2,3,6,5,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive like this,

```
In [24]: mid = len(lst)//2

In [25]: sorted(lst[:mid]) + sorted(lst[mid:],reverse=True)
Out[25]: [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
```

Comment: This won't work for random ordered lists, nor string lists.

Comment: @U9-Forward Can you explain with a small example?

Comment: Better to use len(lst)//2

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

a = x[:int(len(x)/2)]
b = x[int(len(x)/2):]

print(sorted(a) + sorted(b, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[1,2,3,6,5,4] 
l[0:int(len(l)/2)]+sorted(l[-int(len(l)/2):],reverse=True)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

just using the length slice the list then sort it

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
middle = len(list)//2
print(sorted(list[:middle])+sorted(list[middle:],reverse=True))
```